# Sun Java System Portal Server

Tags: java, system, portal, sun

How can we make a web-src for Access Manager customizations and a par-src for portal server customizations?Are there concrete steps to do this?

Thanks & Regards,
Vivek

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be described in the sun docs [here](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/819-5025/gdxcg?a=view) or [sun docs](http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/sundocs/articles/sjspsacsds.jsp)

Comment: Hi , thanks for these , but I dont see anything pertaining to building web-src for access manager customizations in these links.Also is there any IDE or automated tools using which par-src can be built?